# Does Google Chrome support body onunload() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I m write code as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onBack(){
window.history.forward(-1);}
```

```
<body onunload="onBack();" onpageshow="if (event.persisted) onBack();">
```

Its working on firefox and IE but not on google crome?
Please, Help...... :)

Comment: did you try to alert in onBack function?i mean are you sure onback() function not triggered

Comment: @Yorgo yes. I tried out.

Comment: You may check for support of any method in the Chrome Developer Tools Console. Example: "typeof window.onbeforeunload"

Comment: I tested this in a couple browsers. It works in IE 8, but not in Firefox 11 or Chrome. I'm glad my browser doesn't support this - it has the potential to be abusive.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Are you sure?";
 };
```

Comment: window.onbeforeunload = function() {
 window.history.forward(-1);
 }; I am trying this but its not working only on crome. I want to disable back button.

Comment: Don't disable the back button, it's a dick move and most browsers won't let you do it at all for abuse reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery unload. that supported by all browser

```
$(window).unload(function () {
    alert("byebye");
});
```

in safari and chrome(version 14 and above) onbeforeunload and onunload event is being ignored.

Comment: sorry. window.onbeforeunload is being ignored in safari and chrome(version 14 above). you can't use it.